# SharePoint Online - Application Customizer isn't finding a tag

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

In SharePoint Online I am trying to hide the "See All" link that comes with the out-of-the-box List and Document Library web parts.

So I followed this tutorial, [Build your first SharePoint Framework Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension) and created HelloWorldApplicationCustomizer.ts

Now in that file in the `OnInit()` I do:

```
Dialog.alert(`alert 1`);
```

And that displays alert fine.

But if I add these two lines before the alert then the 'See all' doesn't get hidden and my alert doesn't display.

```
//let seeAllTag:HTMLElement = document.querySelector(`[aria-label="See all"]`)[0] as HTMLElement;
//seeAllTag.style.visibility = `hidden`;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Which "two lines"? Did you forget to add the code to your question?

Comment: Im an idiot!     //let seeAllTag:HTMLElement = document.querySelector(`[aria-label="See all"]`)[0] as HTMLElement;
    //seeAllTag.style.visibility = `hidden`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this code:

```
let seeAllTag: any = document.querySelector(`[aria-label="See all"]`);
if(seeAllTag) {
    seeAllTag.style.visibility = "hidden";
    //seeAllTag.style.display = "none";
}
```

**OR**;

```
let seeAllTag: any = document.querySelectorAll(`[aria-label="See all"]`);
if(seeAllTag.length) {
    seeAllTag[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    //seeAllTag[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

**Note**: It will hide only one 'See all' link on the page for which `aria-label` matches exactly to "See all".

---

If you want to hide all links on the page for which `aria-label` **starts with** "See all", use this code:

```
let seeAllTag: any = document.querySelectorAll(`[aria-label^="See all"]`);
for(let index = 0; index < seeAllTag.length; index++) {
    let seeAllLink = seeAllTag[index];
    seeAllLink.style.visibility = "hidden";
    //seeAllLink.style.display = "none";
}
```

---

**Update**:

You no longer need to use the custom CSS to hide the "See all" link of list/library web parts on modern pages. Microsoft recently introduced a feature using which you can show/hide the "See all" link from web part settings.

Check this article for more information & steps: [Show/Hide See all link from SharePoint list/library web parts](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/11/18/show-hide-see-all-link-from-sharepoint-list-library-web-parts)

Comment: Hi Ganesh thanks again for your help. I get this error unfortunately Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'.ts(2339)

Comment: Are you using exact code as I written or did you make any changes in it?

Comment: Im using the exact code.

Comment: https://ibb.co/WG9jr4P

Comment: style gets underlined in VS Code to show the error thanks

Comment: Try changing first line to : `let seeAllTag: any = document.querySelectorAll(`[aria-label="See all"]`);`

Comment: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(selectors: keyof HTMLElementTagNameMap): NodeListOf<HTMLObjectElement | HTMLElement | HTMLAnchorElement | ... 65 more ... | HTMLVideoElement>', gave the following error.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(selectors: keyof SVGElementTagNameMap): NodeListOf<SVGSymbolElement | SVGAElement |

Comment: `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'` - Where are we using "number" assignment in our code? Last time I checked, it was working correctly for me in SPFx web part. I think I have to try it creating a new SPFx application customizer solution.

Comment: Yeah Im not sure. It has me baffled! If you get a chance to check it yourself let me know. Thanks for all your help P